# Find out specific changes made in Boost between versions

Tags: c++, boost

I've encountered a problem with fast_pool_allocator in Boost 1.51+ which was not present at 1.45. After some research I was able to find out the reason, but now I wonder if it is possible e. g. to find some complete list of changes made in Boost or even list of changes that involve specific classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going through the release notes:

- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_50_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_47_0.html
- http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_46_0.html

Note: beware of intermediate releases (though these usually only contain bugfixes).

Unveiled only this for "Boost Pool" (use incremental search in the browser :))

> [Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html):
>
> - Now can set a max_size for pool (#2696)
> - boost/pool/pool.hpp uses reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast (#2941)
> - boost::pool_allocator now works with vector of vectors (#386)
> - Boost pool is now compatible with Microsoft memory leak detection (#4346)

That'd tip me off to look closer into the changes in Boost Pool in v1.46.0

Answer (score 2):

You can:

Use the [github mirror for boost-svn](https://github.com/ryppl/boost-svn)

Check it out and type

git log --pretty=oneline tagA...tagB

Where tagA and tagB are version tags listed in the github page under branch button.

Or:

Using the github repo and giving it a compare url like this:

https://github.com/ryppl/boost-svn/compare/Boost_1_45_0...Boost_1_51_0

You can see *most recent* commits.

Comment: @sehe too bad they limit the amount of commits when the list is too large. That means for large repos we need to check it out and use git log to see all commits in one place.

Comment: @nurettin I have a feeling you can use the github desktop app to view lists of commits just fine. I haven't tried it, but it would be lacking if you couldn't :)

Comment: @rubenvb listing commits, no problem. I'd be surprised if it let you filter them for subtrees

Comment: @rubenvb sure, since the desktop application has access to the local repository and is able to execute git log command on it.

Comment: @nurettin what I was getting at is that git log isn't the most visually pleasing method of siphoning through commits. Although once you add a path to the command, you get only relevant commits and things become much better `;-)`

Comment: @rubenvb you may be right, I just leave parsing/reducing (path'ing, 'grep'ing, emacs C-s'ing) the output as an exercise to the reader.